# a basic example of the read-tree command usage

Tags: git

I was having an [issue with renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501916/renaming-is-not-reflected-when-changes-pulled/22506372?noredirect=1#comment34276996_22506372) a file and was given a solution which included two git commands - `git read-tree -i HEAD` and `git checkout-index -a -f`. I seems to have figured out what the second one does and tested it, but I can't grasp why I would need the first one even for the simplest case. I thought that it somehow could substitue `git add` command and add a file to index, however when I created a new file and run the command and then checked the contents of index with `ls-files --staged` it didn't show this files as added, so probably my assumption about the purpose of the command is wrong. I also visited [the manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) but still don't understand why I would need that command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git read-tree` goes like this:

1. Parses a "tree-ish" passed to it to find an object existing in the Git repository describing a tree.

   A tree is what represents a directory in Git: this kind of object lists the SHA-1 and filesystem names of blobs (files) and nested trees (of nested directories) comprising the tree.  Each commit references exactly one tree which represents the state of the top-level project directory itself.

   A "tree-ish" is a specification whish Git is able to parse down to the name of a tree object.  For instance, `HEAD` is first parsed as the name of a reference, then the branch it points to is chased to get its tip commit, then it's parsed to get the name of its tree object.
2. Reads the acquired tree object, recursively, and populates *the index* with the information on these objects.  The index does not contain the actual data of the files—only meta information on them.

   IOW, the index is like a miniature filesystem kept in a single file.  Its format is optimized for super-fast access over a huge nested sets of files.

Now another command, `git checkout-index` can be used to bring the work tree in sync with the index.  Commands like `git checkout <commit>` do exactly this: call `git read-tree` to populate the index and then `git checkout-index` to sync the work tree with it.

That's the basics.  The command is able to do more than that:

- If passed the `-m` command line option, it's able to merge the tree(s) passed to it into the index.
- It's able to read the indicated tree in a way so that its files appear (in the index) in a subdirectory of the project (via `--prefix`).
- It's able to empty the index (via `--empty`).

In the simplest form we've called it when we've been dealing with your original problem, it just replaced the contents of the index with what was referenced by `HEAD` at the moment.

Note that `git read-tree` is a *plumbing* command, not intended to be routinely used by users.  It's called automatically when you do things like `git checkout <commit>`.  I've advised to call it directly because who knows if running `git checkout HEAD` would *really* update your index or it would decide that since it anyway reflects the state of the `HEAD` nothing should be done.  Calling it by hand ensured the index started to contain exactly the state we needed.  In the general case you don't need this program and hence that's why it's hard to come up with a trivial usage example.

Comment: @Maximus, you might want to learn the concepts underlying Git better -- see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22178579/720999) for a starter.

Comment: Thanks for you elaborate answer! It seems that `working tree` and `git tree object` are not the same things, right?

Answer (score 2):

The read-tree command takes a git tree object and copies its state into the index. In your case you are taking the tree currently marked as HEAD and resetting the index to match this tree - that is equivalent to *git reset --mixed HEAD*. The first command can be used when you need to bring in a discontinuous history from some other repository (see this [blog entry](http://www.patthoyts.tk/blog/git-merge-disconnected-repositories.html)) such as a converted CVS repository. Once you have the index in a state that matches what you need you can create a commit as normal. The read-tree command is not going to be like *add* - it will not look at anything in the current working folder set. It is doing reset.

Comment: @Maximus, see? The advice to use `git read-tree` was an overengeneering on my part as `git reset --mixed HEAD` does the same thing. Thanks for suggestion, Pat!

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.34 (Q4 2021) illustrates what `git read-tree` is used for, through a bug fix for that feature.

See [commit 0e29222](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e29222e0c2f68118cdd3412515539b74433b732), [commit 94b7f15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94b7f1563ace91af823125e5b8895cb24b2c0e4a), [commit 56d06fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56d06fe4aa9089bccb4ff247fc3224fc7431c72d), [commit 1fdd51a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fdd51aa13c27403c37b57ead32ef79b81d8128b), [commit 480d3d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/480d3d6bf90a6ec5b8f02d672f1d4027a4889106), [commit 1b5f373](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b5f37334a2603c7134da7accba76276d8d31cf6), [commit c42e0b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c42e0b64093306d59372df288f9b4086290623f5), [commit 04988c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04988c8d182da945cd9420274f33487157c5636f), [commit 491a757](https://github.com/git/git/commit/491a7575f188cbf6cfb5be75981a40beb4c22b44), [commit c512d27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c512d27e787e9eb325731ab6aa7ac126f8cf6126) (27 Sep 2021), and [commit 446cc55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/446cc5544a3cb8dbd0ddac5bc5b160a687eb6471) (24 Sep 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 04d3761](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04d3761db214512fa29db39bd43e0b162396045c) (20 Sep 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a7c2daa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7c2daa06d6f7d8fd13a1d72f23741acbaeba522), 13 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`read-tree, merge-recursive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/491a7575f188cbf6cfb5be75981a40beb4c22b44): overwrite ignored files by default
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> This fixes a long-standing patchwork of ignored files handling in read-tree and merge-recursive, called out and suggested by Junio long ago.
> Quoting from [commit dcf0c16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcf0c16ef1a8c2e468afe686a27a5549fea59798) (core.excludesfile clean-up, 2007-11-16, Git v1.5.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1a82fe9a3de780fb2f1fe054d692294544f01e7)) ("core.excludesfile clean-up" 2007-11-16):
>
> > `git-read-tree` takes `--exclude-per-directory=<gitignore>`,
> > not because the flexibility was needed.
> > Again, this was
> > because the option predates the standardization of the ignore
> > files.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > On the other hand, I think it makes perfect sense to fix
> > `git-read-tree`, `git-merge-recursive` and `git-clean` to follow the
> > same rule as other commands.
>
> History shows each of these were partially or fully fixed:
>
> - `clean` was taught the new trick in [1617adc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1617adc7a074415413b2f48da72f43d5c6cd74c4) ("Teach [`git clean`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1617adc7a074415413b2f48da72f43d5c6cd74c4/Documentation/git-clean.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean))</sup> to use `setup_standard_excludes()`", 2007-11-14, Git v1.5.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c6ea3800d1eace51994d90fbeb19ffe918e63b0)).
> - **`read-tree` was primarily used by `checkout` & `merge` scripts**.
>   `checkout` and `merge` later became builtins and were both fixed to use the new `setup_standard_excludes()` handling in [fc001b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc001b526c42e5fb776340136a2fb247e391a61b) ("`checkout,merge`: loosen overwriting untracked file check based on info/exclude", 2011-11-27, Git v1.7.9-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ef569791f967c1559b498d8f77a2c42a14be2ed)).
>   So the primary users were fixed, though `read-tree` itself was not.
> - merge-recursive has now been replaced as the default merge backend by **[`merge-ort`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309)**.
>   `merge-ort` fixed this by using `setup_standard_excludes()` starting early in its implementation; see [commit 6681ce5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6681ce5cf6a869aa73cfe56d041dce133262587a) ("`merge-ort`: add implementation of checkout()", 2020-12-13, Git v2.31.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9d29daba64ae2c81ed62d0c1f4c5e4493247f6b) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72c4083ddf91b489b7b7b812df67ee8842177d98)), largely due to its design depending on `checkout()` and thus being influenced by the checkout code.
>   However, `merge-recursive` itself was not fixed here, in part because its design meant it had difficulty differentiating between untracked files, ignored files, leftover tracked files that haven't been removed yet due to order of processing files, and files written by itself due to collisions).
>
> Make the conversion more complete by now handling `read-tree` and handling at least the `unpack_trees()` portion of `merge-recursive`.
> While merge-recursive is on its way out, fixing the `unpack_trees()` portion is easy and facilitates some of the later changes in this series.
> Note that fixing `read-tree` makes the `--exclude-per-directory` option to `read-tree` useless, so we remove it from the documentation (though we continue to accept it if passed).